# Setup created by WiX bootstrapper is not started

Tags: c#, wix, bootstrapper, wix3.7

I tried to create a setup file using Bootstrapper which is intended to first run the .NET framework setup file and only then the MyApp.exe. After finishing the project I got the final setup file, but even it doesn't get started after double click or pressing enter after selecting the file. I don't know where I was wrong.

This is `program.cs` file:

```
using Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper;
namespace testingBoot
{
    class Program:BootstrapperApplication
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is tesing for the bootStrapper");
            Console.Read();
        }

        protected override void Run()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And my WiX installation file is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">

    <Bundle UpgradeCode="46C265F4-3F60-4781-9EF6-DB889C115D55" Version="1.0.0.0">
        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost" >
            <Payload SourceFile="BootstrapperCore.config" />
            <Payload SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.7\SDK\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll" />
        </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
        <Variable Name="LaunchTarget"
            Value="[ProgramFiles64Folder]Folder\Exe Name.exe"/>
        <Chain>
          <PackageGroupRef Id="Netfx4Full"/>
          <ExePackage SourceFile="$(var.PATH)\testingBoot.exe"/>
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>

    <Fragment>
        <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId"
                     Value="Netfx4Full"/>
        <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl"
                     Value="NetfxLicense.rtf" />
        <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                             Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
                             Value="Version"
                             Variable="Netfx4FullVersion" />
        <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                             Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
                             Value="Version"
                             Variable="Netfx4x64FullVersion"
                             Win64="yes" />

        <PackageGroup Id="Netfx4Full">
            <ExePackage Id="Netfx4Full"
                        Cache="no"
                        Compressed="yes"
                        PerMachine="yes"
                        Permanent="yes"
                        Vital="yes"
                        Name="dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"
                        SourceFile="dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"
                        DetectCondition="VersionNT64" />
        </PackageGroup>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents"
                        Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
            <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
                <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
            <!-- </Component> -->
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

And also I have changed assemblyName under host to my own assembly name as `testingBoot.exe` in configuration file `BootstrapperCore.config`.

Here is my `BootStrapperCore.config` file's contents:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup
            name="wix.bootstrapper"
            type="Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.BootstrapperSectionGroup, BootstrapperCore">

            <section
                name="host"
                type="Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.HostSection, BootstrapperCore" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
    </startup>
    <wix.bootstrapper>
        <host assemblyName="testingBoot" >
            <supportedFramework version="v4\Full" />
        </host>
    </wix.bootstrapper>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your BootstrapperApplication assembly is missing from the `BootstrapperApplicationRef` element. I should also note that the Burn engine loads your BA assembly directly. It does not launch it as an executable. Thus, to get your BootstrapperApplication loaded, I think you'll want to to make the following change:

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost" >

  <Payload SourceFile="$(var.PATH)\testingBoot.exe"/>
  <Payload SourceFile="BootstrapperCore.config" />

  <Payload SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.7\SDK\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll" />
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```

That will add the `testingBoot.exe` to the BootstrapperApplication and if your `BoostrapperCore.config` file looks like:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="wix.bootstrapper" type="Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.BootstrapperSectionGroup, BootstrapperCore">
        <section name="host" type="Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.HostSection, BootstrapperCore" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <wix.bootstrapper>
    <host assemblyName="testingBoot">
        <supportedFramework version="v4\Full" />
        <supportedFramework version="v4\Client" />
    </host>
  </wix.bootstrapper>
</configuration>
```

Then the Burn engine will find an assembly named `testingBoot` and load that. Again, as noted above, `testingBoot` will be loaded directly and the `Run()` method will be called directly. The `Main()` entry point will be skipped because the Burn engine does not run the assembly as an executable.

Comment: Thanks for your response. its seems more reasonable though, i tried this with my project but still have same problem, setup file doesn't start. 

I have edited my question and added the detail of my configuration file too.

Comment: encase you need more details about my project, i have uploded my project here w.mediafire.com/download.php?em5e83p03jo8zsr
its in VS2012 and uses WIX3.7.